# Stop screen tearing with JavaFX AnimationTimer

Tags: java, animation, javafx

In JavaFX, it seems appropriate to me to use AnimationTimer for frequently updating Canvas Nodes; that is, for rasterized animations instead of vector animations. I'm running into an issue, which may be VSync related. I have a singular Canvas on my Scene which contains 2D data that changes frequently (the rest of the program is done with Nodes). I tend to get a tearing down the middle of the screen when I do this, which implies that the AnimationTimer may be falling out of sync with the monitor refresh rate.

This (simplified) code shows the error in detail. Note that I have no idea whether it's display hardware dependent, and the exact position of the tear may shift slightly.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;

public class BugDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Canvas background = new Canvas();
    private Color bgColor = Color.rgb(0, 0, 0);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();

        startLoops(root);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        initUserControls(scene);
        background.widthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        background.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        root.getChildren().add(background);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Bug Demo");

        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all running control managers for game field
     * @param scene primary scene of game
     */
    protected void initUserControls(Scene scene) {
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                bgColor = Color.rgb((int)((event.getX() / background.getWidth()) * 255),
                        (int)((event.getY() / background.getHeight()) * 255),
                        255);
            }};
        scene.getRoot().setOnMouseMoved(handler);
        scene.getRoot().setOnMouseDragged(handler);
    }

    /**
     * Starts all game loops, which will at the beginning of the simulation and often for the extent
     * of it.
     * @param parent Root node
     */
    protected void startLoops(Parent parent) {
        GraphicsContext gc = background.getGraphicsContext2D();

        new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                drawBackground(gc);
            }}.start();
    }

    protected void drawBackground(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(bgColor);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
    }

}
```

Moving the mouse cursor over the scene will cause the canvas to shift in background color. As you move the mouse, you will notice (presumably) a tearing in the frame.

It is quite possible that I'm simply being a N00B at JavaFX, and there's a perfectly friendly .sync()-ish method I'm supposed to call somewhere; but I haven't found it yet. I've found bugs submitted to Oracle that look *similar* to this. My answer may simply be dodging using Canvas and AnimationTimer for animations. All the same, even if there isn't a solution at this time, if someone has a workaround, I would love to hear about it!

Thanks!

Comment: I see no tearing whatsoever, even when I run with `-Dprism.order=sw`, which leads me to suspect it's a video driver issue.  Have you tried it on some different machines?

Comment: It has occurred to me to try running it under a different operating system on this machine, too; just for the sake of determining whether the problem is more likely with the software end or the hardware end. I'll pack it into a jar file and report back after the deed is done.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue (thank you to @VGR for pointing out the lack of system behavioral congruity)! Seems that it wasn't Java at all; it was Marco. I switched Desktop Windowing Managers, to Compiz specifically; and the tearing is now gone.

Evidently this isn't a bug in Java at all; it's a trade-off for using Marco. This is a relief!